# Pegar dados de duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo, logo quando inicia a sessão

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Estou tentando pegar dados de duas tabelas logo no inicio da sessão quando o usuário realiza o login, quando utilizo o

```html
SELECT * FROM usuarios, orders WHERE email = '$login' and senha= '$senha'
```

Consigo realizar o login tranquilamente, até ai de boa, mais quando modifico o código para

```html
$comando="SELECT * FROM usuarios INNER JOIN orders ON usuarios.id_usuario = orders.id_usuario WHERE email.usuarios='$login' and senha.usuarios='$senha'";
```

Ele só me deixa fazer login se o usuário já tiver algum orders (pedido). O que estou tentando fazer é assim que o usuário loga, mostre também os pedidos que ele já fez etc, que são dados que estão em outra tabela. Alguém consegue ver meu erro?

Answer (score 1):

Ignorando outros possíveis problemas. O que você provavelmente quer fazer um `LEFT JOIN` e não um `INNER JOIN`.

Experimente usar o [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html), ao invés do [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN orders ON usuarios.id_usuario = orders.id_usuario WHERE email.usuarios='$login' and senha.usuarios='$senha'
```

O `LEFT JOIN` deve obter todos os dados do `usuarios` e, se houver algum *match* ele irá pegar os `orders`. [Existe esta resposta com uma comparação entre todos os `JOIN`.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/15089) *Note que está usando `email.usuarios`, talvez seja `usuarios.email`, mas apenas copiei como está na sua pergunta.*

Comment: Pessoalmente, eu ainda preferiria fazer duas queries distintas, em funções distintas.

Comment: Agora não consigo pegar alguns dados da tabela como ID_usuario

Comment: Os usuarios que tem orders(pedidos) eu consigo pegar o id_usuario da tabela usuarios, mais aqueles que não tem orders, ele não me retornar o id_usuario

Comment: Isso é porque o `id_usuario` está presente nas duas tabelas,é ambíguo, então se tentar pegar `id_usuario` ele pegará de qualquer uma. Você tem que especificar `usuarios.id_usuario` (não uso mais PHP, não me lembro se era possível) ou selecionar com um alias (`SELECT *, usuarios.id_usuario as id_usuario FROM ....`), dessa forma você força que `id_usuario` seja o `usuarios.id_usuario`.

Comment: Então ficaria "SELECT usuarios.id_usuario as id_usuario * FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN orders ON usuarios.id_usuario = orders.id_usuario WHERE usuarios.email='$login' and usuarios.senha='$senha'"  ?

Comment: @Edvan, basicamente. Mas, o `*` tem que vim sempre antes (`SELECT *, usuarios.id_usuario as id_usuario FROM ...`) e não (`SELECT usuarios.id_usuario as id_usuario, * FROM ....`), ou substitua com as colunas que realmente está usando (o que é preferível).

Comment: Massa irmão que Deus o abençoe :)

Comment: Por exemplo se eu tiver 2 pedidos do mesmo ID_usuario, tem como fazer ele me retornar todos os pedidos feitos pelo mesmo ID_usuario, ou eu teria que usar uma nova query com WHILE?

Comment: Cada pedido será uma linha, você vai ter que acessar cada um usando o `mysqli_fetch` normalmente. Você pode fazer um `foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result) as $row) {
// var_dump($row);
}`

Comment: Tem como eu fazer isso usando os dados que já tenho da SESSION do usuário, ou vou ter que fazer uma nova consulta SQL

Comment: Perdoe-me se estou sendo incomodo, não tenho muita familiaridade com PHP